How do I get a list of Service Principals in Azure via the CLI
When I run az ad sp list, I get a list of service principals which includes an accountEnabled attribute:

I adjusted the command to show only the ones that are enabled using this command:
az ad sp list | where-object { $_.AccountEnabled -eq 'true' }

However, when I do, I get no results. What's the correct method for listing the active Service Principals?

I don't have any experiences with the Azure CLI but I'd expect it to return text instead of objects like the PowerShell does. So you cannot use the dot notation $_.AccountEnabled. I'd recommend using the proper according PowerShell cmdlet instead of az ad sp list.  ... something like Get-AzADServicePrincipal might bring you a step further.

Use this query az ad sp list --filter "accountEnabled eq true" --output json, and let me know this works for you or not

Thank you Olaf and Pratik. Both worked. Olaf, I definitely wanted the PowerShell object capability so if you can put that as an answer, I'll accept it. Bottom line, there are AZ only commands which I was using instead of powershell which I actually wanted.

More generally, the output from any az command can be piped into convertfrom-json to return structured in-memory objects that can be further processed - in your case $spns = az ad sp list | convertfrom-json | where-object { $_.accountEnabled }


To list the service principal based on accountEnabled = true using Azure CLI

When I ran, the command mentioned by you, I got following response:
az ad sp list | where-object { $_.AccountEnabled -eq 'true' }

Response:

To resolve the error use this modified command:
az ad sp list --filter "accountEnabled eq true" --output json

Response:

To list the service principal with accountEnabled = true using PowerShell, use this:
Get-AzADServicePrincipal 
    | Where-Object { $_.AccountEnabled -eq $true } 
    | Select-Object DisplayName, AppId, AccountEnabled

Response:

References:

az ad sp list

Get-AzADServicePrincipal



This solved my problem which other people already mentioned in comments above, but you solved my next issue where the return values were bad because I was using strings for true and false. Using $true and $false gives the correct values apparently. Not sure why it returned them at all if string values were wrong, but cest la vie.
